# 複数の文字列から同じ部分を抜き出す方法

Tags: ruby

```
text_1 = 'hogeあいうえお'
text_2 = 'hogeかきくけこ'
text_3 = 'hogeさしすせそ'

期待値 => 'hoge'
```

---

```
text_1 = 'hogeあいうえお'
text_2 = 'hogeあいうえおかきくけこ'
text_3 = 'hogeあいうさしすせそ'

期待値 => 'hogeあいう'
```

「前方の一致部分」に限ります。

これをrubyで実現したいのですがどうしたらよいのか全くわかりません。
わかる方いましたらお願いします。

Comment: StackOverFlow に同じ様な質問と[回答](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1916480)がありました。

Answer (score 1):

`differ`というライブラリを使うのが簡単です。

```sh
$ gem install differ
```

```rb
require 'differ'

def diff(strs)
  strs.reduce do |s1, s2|
    s = Differ.diff_by_char(s1,s2).to_s
    s[0..s.index('{')-1]
  end
end

list1 = ['hogeあいうえお','hogeかきくけこ','hogeさしすせそ']
list2 = ['hogeあいうえお','hogeあいうえおかきくけこ','hogeあいうさしすせそ']


puts diff(list1) # hoge
puts diff(list2) # hogeあいう
```

簡単に解説すると、`Differ.diff_by_char()`というメソッドは以下のように２つの文字列を文字単位で比較し、差分を返します。

```rb
require 'differ'

puts Differ.diff_by_char('abc','abd').to_s
# ab{"d" >> "c"}

puts Differ.diff_by_char('ab','abc').to_s
# ab{-"c"}
```

そのため、比較対象の文字列に`{`が入っていないことを前提とすると、差分のうち`{`が現れる前までの文字列を前方一致箇所とみなすことができます。

#### 追記:

以下のように書き直すと、対象文字列に`{`が含まれていた場合でも正確に対応できます。

```rb
require 'differ'

def diff(strs)
  strs.reduce do |s1, s2|
    diff = Differ.diff_by_char(s1,s2)
    raw = diff.send(:raw_array)
    (raw[0].is_a? String)? raw[0]: ''
  end
end

list1 = ['hoge{あいうえお','hoge{かきくけこ','hoge{さしすせそ']
list2 = ['hogeあいうえお','hogeあいうえおかきくけこ','hogeあいうさしすせそ']


puts diff(list1) # hoge{
puts diff(list2) # hogeあいう
```

Answer (score 0):

（自分はRubyに不慣れなので参考程度に考えてください。）

各行の処理についてはコメントを見てください。また最初に文字列を配列に格納するところは省略しています。

```
# coding: utf-8
# words = ['hogeあいうえお','hogeかきくけこ','hogeさしすせそ']
words = ['hogeあいうえお','hogeあいうえおかきくけこ','hogeあいうさしすせそ']
# words = ['a','a','a']
# words = ['a','a','i']
# words = ['','a','a']
# words = ['','','']
# words = []
m = words.map{|v|v.length}.min
p words.map{|v| v[0,m].chars.to_a} #一番短い文字列の長さに合わせる
   .transpose # 転置
   .take_while{|v| v.all?{|i|i==v[0]}} # 全ての要素が等しい配列が続く限り取り出す
   .map {|v| v.first} # 各配列の先頭を取り出す
   .inject(""){|str,c| str+c} # 文字列にまとめる
```

```sh
$ ruby commonseq.rb
"hogeあいう"
```

`transpose`の返す配列は自身が空、もしくは空でない要素を持つので、後続の操作は安全です。